# Is Firebase Instance token compatible with Google InstanceID API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

There is a [Google Instance ID API.](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/) Can it be used with Firebase Instance ID tokens? Are they one and the same? There is no mention on either of the documentation sites about whether Firebase Instance IDs are compatible with the "Instance ID API."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google InstanceID API service you linked and the InstanceID service by FCM (and the GCM version before that) use the same InstanceID service.